# AppleScript cURL and parse URL

Tags: applescript, automator, osx-snow-leopard

I am working on a Automator workflow, I am passing list of URLs to the "Run Applescript" and I need to fetch the contents of  on each page, concatenate and pass it to a BBedit (or any other text editor).

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "BBEdit"
        activate

        set astid to AppleScript's text item delimiters

        set startHere to "<tbody>"
        set stopHere to "</tbody>"

        repeat with anItem in input

            set blurb0 to (do shell script "curl " & anItem)
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startHere
            set blurb1 to text item 2 of blurb0
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to stopHere
            set blurb2 to text item 1 of blurb1

            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid

            return blurb2
            beep

        end repeat      

    end tell

end run
```

The current code only properly gets only the contents from first URL. Can anybody fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This subroutine may be what you need (if you're using Safari)...

```
on getSource(this_URL)
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        set the URL of the current tab of document 1 to this_URL
        set the |source| to the source of the front document
    end tell
    tell application "TextEdit"
        activate
        set the text of the front document to the source
    end tell
    quit application "Safari"
end getSource
```

Call it using:

```
repeat with anItem in input
    getSource(input)
end repeat
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are inside the `repeat with anItem in input` loop it does all your work for the first item and the `return` exits the loop and in fact the whole Automator action. I think you have never heard the `beep` from your script ;-)

On the other side I'm wondering why you want BBEdit to do the cUrl and sort work for you. All called handlers don't belong to BBEdit...

I think your handler should look like this:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    -- define a few parameters
    set astid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set startHere to "<tbody>"
    set stopHere to "</tbody>"

    -- define a list to store all found content
    set allFoundContent to {}

    repeat with anItem in input

        set blurb0 to (do shell script "curl " & anItem)
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startHere
        set blurb1 to text item 2 of blurb0
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to stopHere

        -- put the found content at the end of the list
        set end of allFoundContent to text item 1 of blurb1

        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid

    end repeat

    -- from here you have three possibilities:
    -- 1. return the list to next Automator action (uncomment the next line):

    -- return allFoundContent


    -- 2. concatenate the list with a delimiter you like (here return & "------" & return)
    -- and give it to your preferred text editor from this point (uncomment the next lines):

    -- set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return & "------" & return
    -- tell application "TextEdit"
    --     make new document with properties {text: allFoundContent as text}
    -- end tell
    -- set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid


    -- 3. concatenate the list with a delimiter you like (here return & "------" & return)
    -- and give it to the next workflow step, maybe a BBEdit action waiting for a string? (uncomment the next lines):

    -- set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return & "------" & return
    -- set returnString to allFoundContent as text
    -- set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid
    -- return returnString


    -- Next decision (for choice 1 or 2):
    -- What do you want to give to next Automator action?

    -- you can pass your input (the given URLs) (uncomment next line):
    -- return input

    -- or your result list (uncomment next line):
    -- return allFoundContent
end run
```

Greetings, Michael / Hamburg